# Creating a navigation link to my front-page

Tags: links

I have a menu linking to each of my pages, but I cannot seem to get the link to my front-page working...What is the correct way in Wordpress to link back to your front-page? This works for all of the other pages, just not for my front-page:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_page_link( get_page_by_title( 'Home Page' )->ID ); ?>"> Home. </a>
```

My front-page template does have the "Home Page" name so I'm not sure why this works with all of the other pages but not this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`home_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url), which will point to the Site URL regardless of reading settings and/or what page it is:

```
echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );
```